# Inserting a properties file with MySQL credentials showing when run as Java Application but null when ran as WebService

Tags: java, mysql, web-services, import, properties

I am trying to import a properties file to my java project. I had the web service and database working perfectly before I decided to add a properties file. Since I don't want to have my credentials in my file, I decided to go to with a properties file. The code has no errors and even spits out the contents of my property files with the System.out.println's I have below. When I run the web-service, it compiles then says: 
null
DB_DRIVER
No suitable driver found for DB_CONNECTION

```
private static final String DB_DRIVER = ("DB_DRIVER");
private static final String DB_CONNECTION = ("DB_CONNECTION");
private static final String DB_USER = ("DB_USER");
private static final String DB_PASSWORD = ("DB_PASSWORD");

public static void main(String[] String) {
    //declare reader object outside of Try for scoping
    FileReader reader;
    try{
        reader = new FileReader("ExchangeService.properties");
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.load(ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream("ExchangeService.properties"));
        String driver = properties.getProperty(DB_DRIVER);
        System.out.println(driver);
        String connection = properties.getProperty(DB_CONNECTION);
        System.out.println(connection);
        String user = properties.getProperty(DB_USER);
        System.out.println(user);
        String password = properties.getProperty(DB_PASSWORD);
        System.out.println(password);
        reader.close();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

MORE CODE (INsert data Into collection) blah=blah

```
      public static  Connection getDBConnection() {
    Connection  dbConnection = null;

    try {

        Class.forName(DB_DRIVER);

    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {

        System.out.println(e.getMessage());

    }

    try {

        dbConnection = DriverManager.getConnection(
        DB_CONNECTION, DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD);
        return dbConnection;

    } catch (SQLException e) {

        System.out.println(e.getMessage());

    }

    return dbConnection;

}
```

}

Properties file:

```
     DB_DRIVER=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
     DB_CONNECTION=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/exchangeinformation
     DB_USER=root
     DB_PASSWORD=admin
```

Any help would be awesome!

Thanks

Comment: can you show the code where you save these properties (DB_DRIVER,... etc) and where they are defined

Comment: Are you talking about my properties file? If so that that is the last bit of code up there under Properties file.

Comment: No, I am assuming you (as Kevin said) that you saving your configuration to static variables so that you can use them later in your code. this code `dbConnection = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_CONNECTION, DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD);` is should be referencing static variables in the same class. you should also set these variables before using them by the configuration in your properties file

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is all of your code, then this line:

> dbConnection = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_CONNECTION,
>   DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD);

is referencing the private static final String constants, not the values that you are reading from the properties file.

Comment: How should I reference that there then? I am setting my values from the private static final strings too string names (driver, connection, user, password) and the only values that don't give me an error in the DB connection line are the values in the private static string. I tried setting them to the strings I created, but it didn't help. What else could I do?

Comment: When you're reading your property files right now you're setting the values into local variables in your main() method. Local variables are only visible within the scope where they are declared. You need to set them to instance properties on your class instead. If you then run into an issue where in your static method you cannot reference non-static fields, you should move this initialization out of the main(). The only thing your main() needs to do is instantiate your class then call a method on it to kick off your logic